# How can I prevent vue-router from replacing the content loaded into one <router-view> when I load content into another <router-view>?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My Vue app contains two main router-views: one inside of a modal, allowing content to be loaded inside said modal, and another inside the main page. I differentiate between them using the `name` attribute. Here is a piece of code in the `routes.js` file which would load content into the modal, for example.

```
export default ({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/classComp/create',
            components: {
                modalView: createClass
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Essentially, my issue is that, when I load content into the router, the content in the router-view for the main page disappears. I understand that most people use the children attribute to address this, but that is not feasible in this case. For instance, the user can press a router-link button in the sidebar to load the form to create classes into the modal. The ability to press this button is thus unrelated to what is loaded or not loaded into the main page, so creating a `children` attribute is not feasible.

In short, how can I get vue-router to load content into the modal's `router-view` without wiping the content of the mainbox's `router-view`?

**EDIT: **Someone suggested to use `keep-alive` for this, but I could not get this to work. Is this a viable suggestion, and, if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: I believe this would only work if your modal's router-view was a child of the main one. You should check out [Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

Comment: What if I want to load content into the modal without content being inside the main one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking over your use-case again, I don't think nested routes it the way to go.
Unless you really want to have a route that points to your modal, you can use something like [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) to push the modal into another view.

If you are using vue 3, it comes with a component that accomplishes something similar: [Teleport](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html#using-with-vue-components)

EDIT - continuing our conversation from the comments

> As I understand it, portal allows you to insert HTML into two separate locations at once from a single route; my issue is that I need to have 2 routes loaded simultaneously.

You're right, portal won't really allow you to change that. The problem is that vue-router does not have native support for simultaneously loading two routes (unless one is a child of the other). A couple things you could try:

- Add a `modal` nested route (`route.children`). This would allow you to use `<router-view name="modal">` and not navigate away from the parent view. I don't think this makes a lot of sense though. You could do it programmatically using `router.addRoutes`
- Have two routers and two vue apps. I don't believe that vue-router has native support for loading two routes at the same time (unless one is a child of the other). You could however have a separate vue instance just for your modal code. This might introduce complexities based on the design of your app though. A quick example:

```
const appRouter = new VueRouter({ ... })
const modalRouter = new VueRouter({ mode: 'abstract', ... })
Vue.prototype.$modalRouter = modalRouter
const mainApp = new Vue({ router: appRouter })

mainApp.mount('#app')

....
App.vue
-------
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
    <div id="modal-app" v-pre>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const modalApp = new Vue({ router: this.$modalRouter })
    modalApp.mount('#modal-app')
  }
}
</script>
```

You could call `this.$modalRouter.push` anywhere in your app to update the route for it.

Both of those solutions seem a bit hacky to me. The easiest way to do this is probably not to use vue-router at all. With portal-vue you could mount content into your modal from anywhere in the app. You can even do it programmatically with [Wormhole.open()](https://portal-vue.linusb.org/api/wormhole.html#open).

Comment: If I changed to vue3, how much of my vue2 code would be rendered non-functional?

Comment: What do you think of the suggestion to use `keep-alive`?

Comment: I don't think `keep-alive` will do what you want. This is for cases where you don't want to show the component for now, but you will again soon. Using `keep-alive` the component stays in memory.

Comment: Hm. So, how would I have a route that points to my modal which prevents the content in the main box from getting wiped?

Comment: Like I said, `keep-alive` is not what you want. Here are the docs on it: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#keep-alive. Portal is really the solution for what you're trying to do, in my opinion. It's not hard to set up.

Comment: I'm not sure portal would necessarily work here. As I understand it, portal allows you to insert HTML into two separate locations at once from a single route; my issue is that I need to have 2 routes loaded simultaneously. Is this possible using portal?

Comment: Updated my answer with some more thoughts. I hope that helps.

Comment: Two vue instances is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad that solved your problem. Can you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: Yeah, I just did.